# Same predictions for different images

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have my model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1. / 255),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ]
)
```

I have 5 classes
car, cat, chicken, dog, horse

- training data 5x2000 images
- validation data 5x500

model:

[image]

When it predicts different data, I always get similar results:

['car', 'cat', 'chicken', 'dog', 'horse']

Image 1 (dog1):
[4.9049326e-05 9.5814574e-01 6.7946487e-03 3.1311907e-02 3.6987378e-03]

**when I convert softmax to probability:
exp(ClassPredicton)/Allsum[exp(classPrediction)]**
in percents:

- car : 15.040055683750603
- cat : 39.20536775062618
- chicken : 15.14185236104108
- dog : 15.517677159744336
- horse : 15.095047044837798

Image 2 (dog2):
[4.7902806e-05 9.5800018e-01 6.8057855e-03 3.1406440e-02 3.7395945e-03]
in percents:

- car : 15.040560609021316
- cat : 39.20102213297701
- chicken : 15.14254728559979
- dog : 15.519683200882788
- horse : 15.096186771519097

Image 3 (cat):
[4.9812690e-05 9.5811051e-01 6.7795026e-03 3.1328302e-02 3.7318484e-03]
in percents:

- car : 15.04019344328842
- cat : 39.204318323945685
- chicken : 15.141750739426078
- dog : 15.518062778888812
- horse : 15.095674714451008

Image 4 (horse):
[5.0302799e-05 9.5900232e-01 6.7303632e-03 3.0549940e-02 3.6671078e-03]
in percents:

- car : 15.037015141121318
- cat : 39.230982299315045
- chicken : 15.137799886239625
- dog : 15.502703865768133
- horse : 15.091498807555878

Image 5 (car):
[4.7343427e-05 9.5923918e-01 6.6654747e-03 3.0411394e-02 3.6366030e-03]
in percents:

- car : 15.036118926399164
- cat : 39.238056195368415
- chicken : 15.135960560618733
- dog : 15.499678844894094
- horse : 15.090185472719597

I tried to resize the fully connected layer to:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),

or
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
or

tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
```

To no avail, anyone knows how to make the network not show one class all the time?
And what is this problem about?

Edit (save and convert):

```
model.save(foldername + '/' + 'myModel.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open(foldername + "/model.tflite", 'wb') as f:
   f.write(tflite_model)
```

EDIT:
Prediction(.tflite model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")
tflite_interpreter.allocate_tensors()

import cv2
import numpy as np
src = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
input_data = cv2.resize(src, (150,150), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
input_data = input_data.astype(np.float32)
input_data /= 255.
input_tensor = np.array(np.expand_dims(input_data, 0))
input_index = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, input_tensor)
tflite_interpreter.invoke()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()
output_data = tflite_interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
preds = np.squeeze(output_data)

labels = ['car', 'cat', 'chicken', 'dog', 'horse']
print(preds)
sum = 0.0
for i in range(5):
    tmp = preds[i]
    exp = np.exp(tmp)
    sum += exp
    print("it: "+str(i)+" softmax: "+str(tmp)+" exp: "+ str(exp)+ "  sum: "+str(sum))
print(sum)
for i in range(5):
    tmp = np.exp(preds[i])/sum
    tmp = tmp*100
    print(labels[i]+ ' : '+ str(tmp))
```

Result: [4.7343427e-05 9.5923918e-01 6.6654747e-03 3.0411394e-02 3.6366030e-03]

Prediction in .h5:

```
import keras
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
testimage = keras.utils.load_img('./files/'+'car.jpg',target_size=(150,150))
x = keras.utils.img_to_array(testimage)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
from tensorflow import keras
my_model = keras.models.load_model('myModel.h5')
print(str(my_model.predict(x)))
```

Result: [0.92342097 0.03482366 0.00173459 0.03841953 0.00160139]

Comment: Are you predicting in a loop?

Comment: no, each painting separately:

Comment: I think the problem is that you are rescaling the image twice: first as part of your model and then when you load the image to predict.

Comment: After training, the model saves. Then I load it and only then is Image Scaling and Prediction.
Does not scale the same image twice.
And model.tflite implements to the mobile application, the results are the same

Comment: [Does the top answer here help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184648/1676589)

Comment: It doesn't work at all, most are deprecated.
And if You trust them: "you just found a bug in the Keras module but it seems in later versions they have already solved it"  - first coment (2020)

Comment: have you checked your dataset distribution? maybe you have an unbalanced datasets (also, your Conv2D kernel size seems a bit odd to me)

Comment: I have 10,000 different photos in 5 different classes, what do you mean by 'dataset
 distribution '?? @AlbertoSinigaglia 
3x3 is a strange kernel size?

Comment: the target distribution, X images of cat, Y images of dogs...

Comment: the model after training is saved in a .h5 file:
and h5 predictions:
[0.92342097 0.03482366 0.00173459 0.03841953 0.00160139]
But in .tflite model:
[4.7343427e-05 9.5923918e-01 6.6654747e-03 3.0411394e-02 3.6366030e-03]
In Edit I give how to save and convert model

The prediction in tflite is only bad.
Maybe a conversion?

Comment: Sorry, it's still bad - for this picture it only turned out well.
And the results are similar for everyone else in a different class

Comment: I don't know how to check target distribution? Could you please provide more information about what's going on? @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: you should have a 1-hot encoded vector, to check the distribution you just need to do the following `print(one_hot_targets.sum(axis=0))`

Comment: There are no differences in this case: 

`res = my_model.predict(x) 
print(str(res)+'\n') 
y = res.sum(axis=0) 
print(y)
`
[[0.92342097 0.03482366 0.00173459 0.03841953 0.00160139]] 
[0.92342097 0.03482366 0.00173459 0.03841953 0.00160139] 

The values ​​are the same, but in an array with different dimensions

When predicting with .tflite, the model obtains a 1-hot coded vector

@AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: no. you have to do it with your targets, not with your predictions

Comment: input shape, must be in (1, 150 150, 3) 
I cannot do this in input.
Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about .I don't think that's the problem here